# How to set window-size to fullscreen for headless-chrome using chrome options?

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-headless

When executing UI tests, I get an error that selenium doesn't support automatic window resizing for chromedriver, which results in tests failing.

Is there a way to set this using chrome-options for `headless-chrome` ?

I have tried the following,

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
```

Also, replacing `"--start-maximized"` with `"--start-fullscreen"` and `"--kiosk"`.

But none of the above worked for me, the only option that works for me is `"--window-size=width,height"`.

I do not want to hard-code values for width and height, is there some way I can do this to set fullscreen ?

Comment: Related issue: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=737535

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43542208/6513289) can also be helpful for people who are facing this issue.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem is that headless mode is meant to be used on computers without screens, so there's no way for it to figure out what size your screen is even if you have one. The only way is for you to pass that information to the browser with --window-size.

The default window size and display size in headless mode is 800x600 on all platforms.

So the maximized window size is not applicable for chrome-headless and needs to be explicitly set by users, if required.

Answer (score 3):

It worked for me and I've tested this with 6000x6000 window size.
below answer helped. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43542208/2315972)

code for c#

```
    var options = new ChromeOptions(); 
    options.AddArgument("no-sandbox");
    options.AddArgument("headless");
    options.addArguments("window-size=1920,1080");
    IWebDriver _driver= new ChromeDriver($@"path to chrome web driver folder", options, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(130))
```

;

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me `driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1600,700));`

Comment: `driver.set_window_size(1600,700)`

Answer (score 0):

There is another option. Instead of `--start-maximized` option, you can do:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

Comment: `driver.maximize_window()`