# chromedriver screen maximize not happening in LINUX based system + selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

chrome-driver screen maximize is not working in Linux based system, however on windows based system it's working fine.

here is code for headless cases:

````
case "chrome-headless":
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.whitelistedIps", "");
            ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions()
                    .addArguments("--headless=new")
                    .addArguments("disable-infobars") // disabling infobars
                    .addArguments("--disable-extensions") // disabling extensions
                    .addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage") // overcome limited resource problems
                    .addArguments("--no-sandbox") // bypass OS security mode
                    .addArguments("--window-size=1920,1080"); // set size for browser as start-maximized is not working
            driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
            logger.debug("Chrome headless driver instance has been created");
            Reporter.log("Chrome headless driver");
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            break;```
````

FYI, I'm using latest version of selenium(4.11.0)

can anyone please help me out why chrome-driver screen maximize not working?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set window-size to fullscreen for headless-chrome using chrome options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44796194/how-to-set-window-size-to-fullscreen-for-headless-chrome-using-chrome-options)

Comment: The accepted answer in the linked question that @Shawn has provided it the correct solution and reason