# How can I set the Chrome browser window size when running a Selenium node as a windows service?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

I am trying to launch Selenium nodes (Chrome browser) as Windows on the Amazon Windows AMI for running tests, but the browser size it not getting maximized.

I tried all possible solutions provided and it did not work.

*[How can I set the browser window size when using `google-chrome --headless`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43541925/how-to-set-the-browser-window-size-when-using-google-chrome-headless)*

Comment: Please post what you've actually tried so we don't have to guess. A lot of people post that they've tried all possible solutions but if that were really true, they wouldn't be here asking for a solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `aDriver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(width, height));` try it with `aDriver.manage().window().setRect({ width: 400, height: 700, x: 0, y: 0 });`.

This should work for you.

```
public static void setMaximize(boolean maximize) {
if (maximize) {
    if (getHeadless()) {
        aDriver.manage().window().setRect({ width: 1600, height: 900, x: 0, y: 0 });
    } else if (getDevice() == null) {
        try {
            aDriver.manage().window().maximize();
        } catch (WebDriverException e) {
            String name = getDriver();
            if (name == null) {
                System.out.println("Browser has not been set");
            } else {
                System.out.println(name + " does not support maximize");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in *setSize()* in Selenium:

```
    aDriver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(width, height));
```

It works like a champ. I've used it for Firefox, Chrome (even headless), and [Edge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Edge).

**Adding full maximize code**

```
public static void setMaximize(boolean maximize) {
    if (maximize) {
        if (getHeadless()) {
            aDriver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1600, 900));
        } else if (getDevice() == null) {
            try {
                aDriver.manage().window().maximize();
            } catch (WebDriverException e) {
                String name = getDriver();
                if (name == null) {
                    System.out.println("Browser has not been set");
                } else {
                    System.out.println(name + " does not support maximize");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Scott I did tried it but does not work.WebDriver not able to change state of window size after it launches. It just keep default size.

Comment: @Smore, I added the whole maximize method I use (condensed). I pass in either a true or false if I want the test to run small or full sized. If it's supposed to be maximize, but getHeadless is true, then it forces dimensions.

Comment: -1. It does not work on Chrome MacOs.
```TypeError: driver.manage(...).window(...).setSize is not a function
      at testInitialize (common/common.js:11:27)
      at <anonymous>
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)```

Comment: It works for me. The only thing is setSize takes width and height, not Dimension - `setSize(width, height)`

Comment: @Lewis, per the API, setSize() should be there - https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Window.html#setSize-org.openqa.selenium.Dimension - Although looking at your error you should probably note the class description, _"...synonymous to window.resizeTo() in JS"_

Comment: What programming language is used here? Java? C#?

Comment: @PeterMortensen, Java